# Computing rolling sums efficiently in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Supposing I have a set of transactions (purchases) with dates for a set of customers, I want to calculate a rolling *x* day sum of purchase amount and number of purchases **by customer** in that same window. I've gotten it to work using a window function, but I have to fill in for dates where the customer did not make any purchases. In so doing, I'm using a Cartesian product. Is there a more efficient approach so that it's more scalable as the number of customers – and time window – increases?

**Edit:** As noted in the comments, I'm on PostgreSQL v9.3.

Here's sample data (note that some customers may have 0, 1, or multiple purchases on a given date):

```
| id | cust_id |   txn_date | amount |
|----|---------|------------|--------|
|  1 |     123 | 2017-08-17 |     10 |
|  2 |     123 | 2017-08-17 |      5 |
|  3 |     123 | 2017-08-18 |      5 |
|  4 |     123 | 2017-08-20 |     50 |
|  5 |     123 | 2017-08-21 |    100 |
|  6 |     456 | 2017-08-01 |      5 |
|  7 |     456 | 2017-08-01 |      5 |
|  8 |     456 | 2017-08-01 |      5 |
|  9 |     456 | 2017-08-30 |      5 |
| 10 |     456 | 2017-08-01 |   1000 |
| 11 |     789 | 2017-08-15 |   1000 |
| 12 |     789 | 2017-08-30 |   1000 |
```

And here's the desired output:

```
| cust_id |   txn_date | sum_dly_txns | tot_txns_7d | cnt_txns_7d |
|---------|------------|--------------|-------------|-------------|
|     123 | 2017-08-17 |           15 |          15 |           2 |
|     123 | 2017-08-18 |            5 |          20 |           3 |
|     123 | 2017-08-20 |           50 |          70 |           4 |
|     123 | 2017-08-21 |          100 |         170 |           5 |
|     456 | 2017-08-01 |         1015 |        1015 |           4 |
|     456 | 2017-08-30 |            5 |           5 |           1 |
|     789 | 2017-08-15 |         1000 |        1000 |           1 |
|     789 | 2017-08-30 |         1000 |        1000 |           1 |
```

Here's SQL that produces the totals as desired:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    -- One row per day per user
    WITH daily_txns AS (
        SELECT
             t.cust_id
            ,t.txn_date AS txn_date
            ,SUM(t.amount) AS sum_dly_txns
            ,COUNT(t.id) AS cnt_dly_txns
        FROM transactions t
        GROUP BY t.cust_id, txn_date
    ),
    -- Every possible transaction date for every user
    dummydates AS (
        SELECT txn_date, uids.cust_id
        FROM (
            SELECT generate_series(
                 timestamp '2017-08-01'
                ,timestamp '2017-08-30'
                ,interval '1 day')::date
            ) d(txn_date)
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT cust_id FROM daily_txns) uids
    ),
    txns_dummied AS (
        SELECT 
             d.cust_id
            ,d.txn_date
            ,COALESCE(sum_dly_txns,0) AS sum_dly_txns
            ,COALESCE(cnt_dly_txns,0) AS cnt_dly_txns
        FROM dummydates d
        LEFT JOIN daily_txns dx
          ON d.txn_date = dx.txn_date
          AND d.cust_id = dx.cust_id
        ORDER BY d.txn_date, d.cust_id
    )

    SELECT
         cust_id
        ,txn_date
        ,sum_dly_txns
        ,SUM(COALESCE(sum_dly_txns,0)) OVER w AS tot_txns_7d
        ,SUM(cnt_dly_txns) OVER w AS cnt_txns_7d
    FROM txns_dummied
    WINDOW w AS (
        PARTITION BY cust_id
        ORDER BY txn_date
        ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW -- 7d moving window
        )
    ORDER BY cust_id, txn_date
    ) xfers
WHERE sum_dly_txns > 0 -- Omit dates with no transactions
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8092f/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` did you want to write `RANGE '6 days' PRECEEDING` ?

This must be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       cust_id
      ,txn_date
      ,SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id, txn_date) sum_dly_txns
      ,SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY txn_date RANGE '6 days' PRECEDING)
      ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY txn_date RANGE '6 days' PRECEDING)
from transactions
ORDER BY cust_id, txn_date
```

**Edit**: Since you are using an old version (I tested the one above on my postgresql 11), the point above will not make much sense so you will need to old-fashioned SQL (that is, witout window functions).
It is a bit less efficient but does a fair job.

```
WITH daily_txns AS (
        SELECT
        t.cust_id
        ,t.txn_date AS txn_date
        ,SUM(t.amount) AS sum_dly_txns
        ,COUNT(t.id) AS cnt_dly_txns
        FROM transactions t
        GROUP BY t.cust_id, txn_date
)
SELECT t1.cust_id, t1.txn_date, t1.sum_dly_txns, SUM(t2.sum_dly_txns), SUM(t2.cnt_dly_txns)
from daily_txns t1
join daily_txns t2 ON t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id and t2.txn_date BETWEEN t1.txn_date - 7 and t1.txn_date
group by t1.cust_id, t1.txn_date, t1.sum_dly_txns
order by t1.cust_id, t1.txn_date
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me on PostgreSQL 9.3 – I get `ERROR:  RANGE PRECEDING is only supported with UNBOUNDED`...

Comment: @jet_atx: you should always mention that in your question if you are using outdated (or even unsupported) versions.

Comment: actually, it's also a bit my fault :) the SQL fiddle that he @jet_atx shared is correctly set to 9.3. I just find using my local database more convenient and did not pay attention

Comment: I added the SQL version in the question text for add'l clarity. Thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name – this works, and I'll keep the `RANGE` solution in mind for when we're on a more modern version of Postgres!